# Adding a prefix to the file names in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, file-rename

How to rename the files which are present in other directory? 
E.g. under the directory `/home/abc/xyz/folder` we have files like `abc.csv`, `xyz.csv`, `pqr.csv` and we need to add prefix to these files `PREFIX_`.

I have tried `ls *.csv | xargs -I {} mv {} PREFIX_{}`. This works under the current directory, i.e. `/home/abc/xyz/folder`.

How to rename those from `/home` directory? Similarly, I tried `ls /home/abc/xyz/folder/*.csv | xargs -I {} mv {} PREFIX_{}` — not working.

Answer (score 3):

there is a tool, named `rename` ;)

```
$ touch {a..z}
$ rename 's/^/xx_/' *
$ ls
xx_a  xx_b  xx_c  xx_d  xx_e  xx_f  xx_g  xx_h  xx_i  xx_j  xx_k  xx_l  xx_m  xx_n  xx_o  xx_p  xx_q  xx_r  xx_s  xx_t  xx_u  xx_v  xx_w  xx_x  xx_y  xx_z
```

you can combine it with find/xargs (i've just played with it a bit)

```
find . -type f | xargs rename 's@(.*)/([^/]+)@$1/prefix_$2@'
```

or you can use -exec, but in this case 1 rename process would be launched for each file that matches the find criteria

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's@(.*)/([^/]+)@$1/prefix_$2@' "{}" \;
```

**note**: on my system `find | xargs` took `61ms` to run , but `find -exec` took `1250ms` ( files matched by find `~52`)

**note**: i've always taught that there is only one rename utility, it even has alternatives support...i've used the one from `perl` package, also named as `prename`

Comment: Better use the `-exec` feature of `find` rather than `xargs`.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: however, in that case a separate process would be launched for each matched file, i usually dont want that, but i added a -exec variant ;)

Comment: @Zoltan Nagy  :Will this work? if I run this above code to rename only those files which are present in one directory , because I dont find any specified path here plz help on this as I said in the question ill be executing the command from /home directory to rename all .csv files in the directory /home/abc/xyz/folder

Comment: There are *multiple* tools named `rename`, and they take different arguments.

Comment: @bastian i updated the answer; i'm using `prename`; you might want to check you current default alternative with: `update-alternatives --query rename`

Comment: @Zoltan Nagy : I need the rename command with full path specified, Didint get ur previous comment

Comment: @bastian i dont really understand...just use: 
`find /tmp/r/ -name '*.csv' | xargs rename -n 's@(.*)/([^/]+)@$1/prefix_$2@'`
remove the `-n` if you are satisfied with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls *.csv| awk '{print "mv /home/abc/xyz/folder/" $0 " /home/abc/xyz/folder/PREFIX_"$0}'|sh
```